# Haskell, recursive function "cannot construct the infinite type"

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to build a recursive function that will help me solve Project Euler [problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15) in Haskell (I'm very new to it), but the compiler tells me:

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
 Relevant bindings include
   grid :: t (bound at 15.hs:1:22)
   r :: t (bound at 15.hs:1:17)
   d :: t (bound at 15.hs:1:15)
   generateTree :: [t] -> t -> [t] (bound at 15.hs:1:1)
 In the expression: generateTree [d + 1, r] grid
 In the expression:
   [generateTree [d + 1, r] grid, generateTree [d, r + 1] grid]
```

I'm not really too sure whats the problems, and I've come across compilers complaining at me in an easier way to understand. Here is my function:

```
generateTree (d:r:_) grid
    | down && right = [generateTree [d + 1, r] grid, generateTree [d, r + 1] grid]
    | down = [generateTree [d + 1, r] grid, -1]
    | right = [-1, generateTree [d, r + 1] grid]
    | otherwise = [d, r]
    where down = elem d [0..grid]
          right = elem r [0..grid]
```

Thanks

Comment: You should provide a type signature for your function generateTree. This will help the compiler understand your intent, and the error messages will become clearer to you.

Comment: @WolfeFan I'll start looking into that too, I just don't understand Haskell enough yet, but thanks!

Comment: In order to solve this problem in the manner you're trying, you need to clarify in code how the grid is stored, how the directions are stored, and what the function's result will be. Those are your next steps; please do them and update your question when they're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing the error is that you're trying to say that `generateTree` returns values like `[-1, [-1, [-1, 0]]]`, which doesn't have a valid type in Haskell.  All values in a list have to have the same type, which means that lists can't be nested like this.  You *could* nest it like `[[[-1]], [[-1], [-1, 0]]]`, but this would have the type `[[[Int]]]`, meaning it could only ever be 3 levels deep.  You want arbitrarily nested levels, so you'll need a new data type that defines such a recursive structure.

Since your function only ever is returning two elements in a list, you could do this with a binary tree.  Luckily, this is pretty simple in Haskell:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Here `Leaf a` represents a single value, and `Node left right` represents a split in the tree, so you could have

```
Node
    (Leaf (-1))
    (Node
        (Leaf (-1))
        (Node
            (Leaf (-1))
            (Leaf 0)
        )
    )
```

<sup>(whitespace added for clarity)</sup>

Which would be equivalent to the invalid list above of `[-1, [-1, [-1, 0]]]`.  Is this more verbose?  Of course, but it allows arbitrary nesting.

Now you just have to modify your function definition to use this type:

```
generateTree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Tree Int
generateTree d r grid
    | down && right = ...
    | down          = ...
    | right         = Node (Leaf (-1)) (generateTree d (r + 1) grid)
    | otherwise     = Node (Leaf d) (Leaf r)
    where
        down = d `elem` [0..grid]
        right = r `elem` [0..grid]
```

I'll let you finish the rest of the definition, this is just an example to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your `generateTree` function returns a list, see:

```
| otherwise = [d, r]
```

But What is the type of `d` and `r`?  `generateTree` returns a list of whatever the `generateTree` function returns (all elements in a list must be the same type):

```
| right = [-1, generateTree [d, r + 1] grid]
```

In other words, your logic is broken.  Learn the type system, learn to write the types and then the error will become apparent.